# error: need to load kernel first

Tags: kernel, grub, tails-os

I tried to download [Tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tails_(operating_system)) on my computer, however, I couldn't do it because in grub there were 2 errors:

> error:/live/vmlinuz has invalid signature
>
> error: you need to load the kernel first

Can anyone please help me with that because I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

Your system has Secure Boot enabled, and Tails apparently has chosen not to get a Secure Boot certificate from Microsoft. You'll probably have to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS settings.

Unfortunately, the availability and names of Secure Boot configuration settings in the BIOS can vary a lot between hardware vendors and models, so you should check your system or motherboard manual first. If you're still unsure after that, you should edit your question to add the make and model of your system or motherboard.